# create an etf portfolio csv data

Tags: r, dataframe, finance

I'm trying to calculate the adjusted sharpe ratio for a portfolio of two or more assets. what I need to do is:

- I load the  two csv  files I generated.

> > structure(list(X.1 = 1:50, X = 1:50, date = structure(1:50, .Label = c("2019-07-01",  "2019-07-02", "2019-07-03", "2019-07-05",
> >     "2019-07-08", "2019-07-09",  "2019-07-10", "2019-07-11", "2019-07-12",
> >     "2019-07-15", "2019-07-16",  "2019-07-17", "2019-07-18", "2019-07-19",
> >     "2019-07-22", "2019-07-23",  "2019-07-24", "2019-07-25", "2019-07-26",
> >     "2019-07-29", "2019-07-30",  "2019-07-31", "2019-08-01", "2019-08-02",
> >     "2019-08-05", "2019-08-06",  "2019-08-07", "2019-08-08", "2019-08-09",
> >     "2019-08-12", "2019-08-13",  "2019-08-14", "2019-08-15", "2019-08-16",
> >     "2019-08-19", "2019-08-20",  "2019-08-21", "2019-08-22", "2019-08-23",
> >     "2019-08-26", "2019-08-27",  "2019-08-28", "2019-08-29", "2019-08-30",
> >     "2019-09-03", "2019-09-04",  "2019-09-05", "2019-09-06", "2019-09-09",
> >     "2019-09-10"), class = "factor"), 
> >         adjClose = c(130.8539817206, 131.863291017, 132.8033339891, 
> >         131.041990315, 131.2201037202, 131.1706277743, 130.4482789642, 
> >         128.7067256684, 128.8551535061, 129.5972926947, 129.2113803166, 
> >         130.6066019911, 130.6164971802, 130.3097463156, 130.5571260452, 
> >         129.8446724242, 130.4086982074, 129.7853012891, 130.0920521537, 
> >         130.1316329104, 130.4482789642, 131.4971690173, 134.103513361, 
> >         135.3428257349, 137.6826474969, 138.783156885, 138.83272938, 
> >         139.1301643497, 138.852558378, 141.7475920835, 141.2617816329, 
> >         144.4443358092, 146.0504846459, 144.8805737649, 142.8084434756, 
> >         144.2857038254, 143.3239974232, 142.37220552, 144.712027282, 
> >         144.1270718415, 146.3479196156, 146.5362950965, 145.9810831529, 
> >         146.0207411489, 146.2092980651, 146.4278025524, 143.7759526384, 
> >         144.7989509198, 142.2265571831, 139.7336196235), lagx = c(NA, 
> >         130.8539817206, 131.863291017, 132.8033339891, 131.041990315, 
> >         131.2201037202, 131.1706277743, 130.4482789642, 128.7067256684, 
> >         128.8551535061, 129.5972926947, 129.2113803166, 130.6066019911, 
> >         130.6164971802, 130.3097463156, 130.5571260452, 129.8446724242, 
> >         130.4086982074, 129.7853012891, 130.0920521537, 130.1316329104, 
> >         130.4482789642, 131.4971690173, 134.103513361, 135.3428257349, 
> >         137.6826474969, 138.783156885, 138.83272938, 139.1301643497, 
> >         138.852558378, 141.7475920835, 141.2617816329, 144.4443358092, 
> >         146.0504846459, 144.8805737649, 142.8084434756, 144.2857038254, 
> >         143.3239974232, 142.37220552, 144.712027282, 144.1270718415, 
> >         146.3479196156, 146.5362950965, 145.9810831529, 146.0207411489, 
> >         146.2092980651, 146.4278025524, 143.7759526384, 144.7989509198, 
> >         142.2265571831), pct_change = c(NA, 0.0076542098, 0.0070784591, 
> >         -0.0134410632, 0.0013573637, -0.0003771877, -0.0055374346, 
> >         -0.0135311755, 0.0011518968, 0.0057265023, -0.0029866748, 
> >         0.0106826275, 7.57575751427131e-05, -0.0023540132, 0.0018948007, 
> >         -0.0054869685, 0.0043250626, -0.0048032937, 0.0023579524, 
> >         0.0003041594, 0.0024273686, 0.0079765219, 0.0194353174, 0.0091568383, 
> >         0.0169943112, 0.0079297042, 0.0003570663, 0.002137818, -0.001999286, 
> >         0.0204238651, -0.0034390792, 0.0220330839, 0.0109972168, 
> >         -0.0080750017, -0.0145098584, 0.0102384388, -0.0067100166, 
> >         -0.0066852368, 0.0161688134, -0.0040586091, 0.0151751236, 
> >         0.001285521, -0.0038033143, 0.0002715915, 0.001289637, 0.0014922336, 
> >         -0.0184443216, 0.0070649564, -0.0180865922, -0.0178406425
> >         ), rollmeanx = c(NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, 
> >         NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, 
> >         NA, 0.0022449273, 0.0020327583, 0.0016836143, 0.0029861115, 
> >         0.002801633, 0.0036635665, 0.0042995146, 0.0045093675, 0.0039069923, 
> >         0.0040805283, 0.0039373228, 0.0032693281, 0.0038882917, 0.0038227304, 
> >         0.004333512, 0.0045939924, 0.0042813625, 0.0044765504, 0.0044354613, 
> >         0.0044811565, 0.0036783992, 0.003643339, 0.0022001886, 0.0011618239
> >         ), rollsdx = c(NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, 
> >         NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, 
> >         0.0077480465, 0.0076691234, 0.0076367931, 0.0078392534, 0.0079349676, 
> >         0.0087510466, 0.0086559326, 0.0082636055, 0.0090514164, 0.0091306015, 
> >         0.0092739515, 0.0093933857, 0.0096997509, 0.0097492652, 0.0099891559, 
> >         0.0098095162, 0.0099469924, 0.0098104499, 0.0098219087, 0.0098046681, 
> >         0.0107849756, 0.010771918, 0.01108063, 0.0116528378), roll_sharpe = c(NA, 
> >         NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, 
> >         NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, 0.2897410646, 0.2650574546, 
> >         0.2204609035, 0.380917847, 0.3530742789, 0.4186432387, 0.4967130412, 
> >         0.5456900702, 0.4316442951, 0.4469068418, 0.4245571962, 0.3480457574, 
> >         0.4008651116, 0.3921044585, 0.4338216423, 0.468319975, 0.4304177896, 
> >         0.4563042904, 0.4515885332, 0.4570431621, 0.3410669895, 0.3382256492, 
> >         0.1985616886, 0.0997030911)), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, 
> >     -50L))
>
> structure(list(X = 1:49, date = structure(1:49, .Label = c("2019-01-02", 
>   "2019-01-03", "2019-01-04", "2019-01-07", "2019-01-08", "2019-01-09", 
>   "2019-01-10", "2019-01-11", "2019-01-14", "2019-01-15", "2019-01-16", 
>   "2019-01-17", "2019-01-18", "2019-01-22", "2019-01-23", "2019-01-24", 
>   "2019-01-25", "2019-01-28", "2019-01-29", "2019-01-30", "2019-01-31", 
>   "2019-02-01", "2019-02-04", "2019-02-05", "2019-02-06", "2019-02-07", 
>   "2019-02-08", "2019-02-11", "2019-02-12", "2019-02-13", "2019-02-14", 
>   "2019-02-15", "2019-02-19", "2019-02-20", "2019-02-21", "2019-02-22", 
>   "2019-02-25", "2019-02-26", "2019-02-27", "2019-02-28", "2019-03-01", 
>   "2019-03-04", "2019-03-05", "2019-03-06", "2019-03-07", "2019-03-08", 
>   "2019-03-11", "2019-03-12", "2019-03-13"), class = "factor"), 
>       adjClose = c(107.6401844169, 108.2682817731, 108.0425592857, 
>       107.9738611374, 108.0621873281, 108.1897696036, 107.9346050527, 
>       108.2192116672, 108.0229312434, 107.9247910315, 107.9149770103, 
>       107.8266508196, 107.6990685441, 107.7677666924, 107.6401844169, 
>       107.8070227772, 107.6401844169, 107.4929740991, 107.8070227772, 
>       108.3958640486, 109.0043333624, 108.621586536, 108.4056780698, 
>       108.5528883877, 108.4841902393, 108.6510285996, 108.7000987055, 
>       108.4743762181, 108.4940042605, 108.4743762181, 108.778610875, 
>       108.778610875, 109.033775426, 109.0730315107, 108.8865651081, 
>       109.1711717227, 109.0926595531, 109.2496838922, 108.9945193412, 
>       108.8178669598, 108.6019584936, 108.7589828327, 108.7197267479, 
>       108.8473090234, 109.1515436803, 109.2496838922, 109.2300558498, 
>       109.4361502948, 109.5637325703), lagx = c(NA, 107.6401844169, 
>       108.2682817731, 108.0425592857, 107.9738611374, 108.0621873281, 
>       108.1897696036, 107.9346050527, 108.2192116672, 108.0229312434, 
>       107.9247910315, 107.9149770103, 107.8266508196, 107.6990685441, 
>       107.7677666924, 107.6401844169, 107.8070227772, 107.6401844169, 
>       107.4929740991, 107.8070227772, 108.3958640486, 109.0043333624, 
>       108.621586536, 108.4056780698, 108.5528883877, 108.4841902393, 
>       108.6510285996, 108.7000987055, 108.4743762181, 108.4940042605, 
>       108.4743762181, 108.778610875, 108.778610875, 109.033775426, 
>       109.0730315107, 108.8865651081, 109.1711717227, 109.0926595531, 
>       109.2496838922, 108.9945193412, 108.8178669598, 108.6019584936, 
>       108.7589828327, 108.7197267479, 108.8473090234, 109.1515436803, 
>       109.2496838922, 109.2300558498, 109.4361502948), pct_change = c(NA, 
>       0.00580130529379156, -0.00208919974584387, -0.000636247954609872, 
>       0.000817364453597674, 0.00117924528324126, -0.00236406619337162, 
>       0.0026299084064227, -0.00181702552912345, -0.000909338910569157, 
>       -9.09421608741455e-05, -0.000819149904301271, -0.00118461818866857, 
>       0.000637464711466883, -0.00118526622925381, 0.00154756486175119, 
>       -0.00154996353084853, -0.00136948781102927, 0.00291306326814199, 
>       0.00543232231753777, 0.0055820653641086, -0.00352367184650867, 
>       -0.00199167119328355, 0.00135611608393343, -0.000633254930957689, 
>       0.00153554331192595, 0.000451426507283543, -0.0020808830183651, 
>       0.000180913613925363, -0.000180946349583393, 0.00279682425113514, 
>       0, 0.00234023402384323, 0.000359906423762952, -0.0017124831003245, 
>       0.00260697590864838, -0.000719683340030535, 0.00143729788046738, 
>       -0.00234107689581361, -0.00162337662311708, -0.00198807157066812, 
>       0.00144378271118579, -0.00036107600685043, 0.001172121540208, 
>       0.00278726847685346, 0.000898311174948939, -0.000179694519491878, 
>       0.00188323917137825, 0.0011644571840243), rollmeanx = c(NA, 
>       NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, 
>       NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, 0.00031862067098972, 0.000116566615996168, 
>       0.000182745925763722, 0.000281463710606259, 0.000264830167591981, 
>       0.000116642517518964, 0.000232323417850645, 0.000104557292577641, 
>       0.00031427773713485, 0.000355611323978903, 0.000466119332375147, 
>       0.000519712801832612, 0.000495718942211888, 0.00058524217844741, 
>       0.000606405037048468, 0.000601392901535568, 0.000565433203128064, 
>       0.000553892802578618, 0.000331113946269068, 0.000149816691434887, 
>       -0.00012032609815416, 9.31190557875071e-05, 0.00031034358624828, 
>       0.000289534272203531, 0.000310150654542886, 0.000325955011790718, 
>       0.000358365497097116), rollsdx = c(NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, 
>       NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, 
>       NA, 0.00268140767467829, 0.00240146073630199, 0.00235743767997561, 
>       0.00236696184695034, 0.0023643008327706, 0.00240605774759231, 
>       0.00234142001164779, 0.00228025110555633, 0.00230711786187933, 
>       0.00229224984050652, 0.0023280202990145, 0.00231052893570155, 
>       0.00233171418775393, 0.00237482539929513, 0.00236032672014123, 
>       0.00235834925288879, 0.00239840602803656, 0.0024087481448098, 
>       0.00240681026318947, 0.00213964886031918, 0.00176319827198963, 
>       0.00160907538291628, 0.00163656991965793, 0.00162551270011354, 
>       0.00161610064622736, 0.00163029258958719, 0.00163996465710043
>       ), roll_sharpe = c(NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, 
>       NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, 0.118825896561196, 
>       0.0485398800130578, 0.0775188787877576, 0.11891349705062, 
>       0.112012043442729, 0.0484786857820375, 0.0992232989787878, 
>       0.0458534116364924, 0.136220928426624, 0.155136372002243, 
>       0.200221335085637, 0.224932392666535, 0.212598501486754, 
>       0.246435876347421, 0.256915719283212, 0.255005869380419, 
>       0.235753744994942, 0.229950484351013, 0.137573763637803, 
>       0.0700192887783178, -0.0682430898814242, 0.0578711580427878, 
>       0.189630508614717, 0.178118738895924, 0.191912957442906, 
>       0.199936510705267, 0.218520256241821)), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, 
>   -49L))

- I choose between the two etfs according to the highest adjusted sharpe ratio  on the last day of the month. (?)

  - I create a new csv file with the same columns calculated every month for the top ranked etf (on a daily basis). (?)
    Desidered output is a file like those above, with data of top ranked etf

I have no idea about how to proceed. This for finding the last month day:

```
library(tidyverse)
library(roll)


library(quantmod)
library(httr)
library(jsonlite)
library(tidyverse)
library(hrbrthemes)
library(dplyr)
library(xts)

xdf <- data.frame()
xdf <- read.csv('tip.csv')

library(timeDate)    
xdf$eom<-timeLastDayInMonth(xdf$somedate)

????

xdf_02 <- xdf %>% mutate(lagx = lag(adjClose)) %>%
  mutate(pct_change = (adjClose - lagx)/adjClose)%>%
  mutate(rollmeanx = roll_mean(pct_change, width = 22),rollsdx = roll_sd(pct_change, width=22)) %>%
  mutate(roll_sharpe = rollmeanx / rollsdx)

write.csv(xdf_02,'tip_r.csv')
```

Tnx to all contributors

Comment: Hey, @Eugenio: at first it looks like you don't have a programming question, but would like someone to do your (home-)work for you. If so, you should search for help somewhere else, if not please ask a question with a minimal reproducible example, the expected output and what you have tried so far.

Comment: Hi, You're plain right. I have edited my post.